# calling a jQuery method from code behind method

Tags: jquery, asp.net, file-upload

I'm working on an image gallery, where the user can upload images. When an image is upload a message shall be visible for some seconds, which I want to do by making a div visible (for like 5 seconds) with jQuery.

The message shall be visible when an upload has completed, which is done through the method below in my code behind file.

I have a separate JS-file with a method that is called when the page has loaded, but I haven't got a clue how to call a function from that file when an image is successfully uploaded.

Is it possible to call a specific jQuery method from the code behind method below. Is there a better way to accomplish what I want?

Thanks in advance.

```
protected void UploadButton_Click1(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    if (Page.IsValid) {
        if (ImageUpload.HasFile) {
            var content = ImageUpload.FileContent;
            var name = ImageUpload.FileName;
            var image = Gallery.SaveImage(content, name);

            fullSizeImage.ImageUrl = "Images/" + image;

            // Show message!
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`ClientScriptManager`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/asz8zsxy.aspx) to register a startup script.

```
// Get a ClientScriptManager reference from the Page class.
ClientScriptManager cs = Page.ClientScript;

// Check to see if the startup script is already registered.
if (!cs.IsStartupScriptRegistered(cstype, csname1))
{
    StringBuilder cstext1 = new StringBuilder();
    cstext1.Append("<script type=text/javascript> alert('Hello World!') </");
    cstext1.Append("script>");

    cs.RegisterStartupScript(cstype, csname1, cstext1.ToString());
}
```